# create post of acf frontend not published and not trashed

Tags: plugin-development

im using advanced custom post pro for user guest post and all works fine.. but in admin post screen the post submitted been draft its ok, but when I click to publish not publishing or when I click trash not trashed is still on draft..

my function.php code :

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post' );

function my_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

```
// bail early if not a new post
if( $post_id !== 'new_post' ) {

    return $post_id;

}


// vars
$title = $_POST['fields']['field_123456'];


// Create a new post
$post = array(
    'post_status'   => 'draft',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_title'    => $title,
);  


// insert the post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );


// return the new ID
return $post_id;
```

}

my archieve.php for acf guest post:

```
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'       => 'new_post',
    'post_status'   => 'draft',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'submit_value'  => 'submit',
    'field_groups'  => array( 423 )
));
```

can you help me,
thank you

Comment: help please my project depends on it

Comment: no respond right now please I need your help